# Apache Camel 2.14 Google Drive component

Tags: apache-camel, google-drive-api

I was playing with the new Google Drive component in an Apache Camel 2.14 application.
At the moment it's not working, this is the application:

```
private String accessToken = ...
private String applicationName = "camel-mytest";
private String clientId = ...
private String clientSecret = ...
private String refreshToken = ...

private List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
camelContext = (CamelContext) applicationContext.getBean("idGoogleDriveCamelContext");
GoogleDriveConfiguration configuration = new GoogleDriveConfiguration();
configuration.setAccessToken(accessToken);
configuration.setApplicationName(applicationName);
configuration.setClientId(clientId);
configuration.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
configuration.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
configuration.setScopes(scopes);

GoogleDriveComponent googleDriveComponent = new GoogleDriveComponent();
googleDriveComponent.setConfiguration(configuration);
camelContext.addComponent("google-drive", googleDriveComponent);
camelContext.start();
```

This is my route:

```
from("google-drive://drive-about/get")
   .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${body}");
```

I've created client ID and client Secret as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server), I get access token and refresh token in the OAuth playground setting *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive* scope.
I've put the Google Drive maven dependency in my pom.xml file.

This is the stacktrace:

```
[2014-09-29 10:35:55,124] Artifact camel-googledrive:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2014-09-29 10:35:55,125] Artifact camel-googledrive:war: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"camel-googledrive-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.Bootstrap.START" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"camel-googledrive-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.Bootstrap.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[google-drive://drive-about/get]] -> [Log... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: google-drive://drive-about/get due to: null
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[google-drive://drive-about/get]] -> [Log... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: google-drive://drive-about/get due to: null
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[google-drive://drive-about/get]] -> [Log... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: google-drive://drive-about/get due to: null
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: google-drive://drive-about/get due to: null
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
```

Is it a component initialization or sintax problem? Thank you

Comment: How did you setup your camel route? If the route is loaded before you setup the googleDriveComponent, you may hit the NPE issue.

Comment: You're great! :) Actually I was declaring the Google Drive component after loading the route, defined in a Java class loaded in the applicationContext.xml file. It has been sufficient set up the component and its configuration in applicationContext.xml before loading the route. Thank you!

Comment: will it work with google service account?